# Jenkins: How to configure Mercurial installer for OSX?

Tags: macos, mercurial, jenkins, hudson

How do I configure Jenkins to automatically install Mercurial on nodes (slaves) that need it?

I tried checking the `Mercurial -> Install Automatically` combo-box under the Master node but it didn't seem to work. Do I need to "Add installer" for this to work? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there are many Jenkins bugs on OSX: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jenkinsci-users/J5FzjoCLxaE/discussion

There doesn't seem to be a way to auto-install Mercurial under OSX at this time. You must install Mercurial manually and point Jenkins to it. Ubuntu deployments can run sudo apt-get install mercurial but I'm not familiar with an equivalent for OSX.